# How to get text flow to start one column at a time for multiple columns?

Tags: multicol

I'm making a document that has 3 columns, but I've noticed that the text spreads over all three columns as I'm typing the document. If anyone is familiar with how multicolumn works in Microsoft Word (or whatever word processor Microsoft uses now), it fills the the text one column at a time. I was wondering if there was a package or some code I could use to get my text to fill this way. This mechanism is okay if I plan to use to whole page, but if my text doesn't take up the whole page, then I have half of my sentence in one column and the other in the 2nd/3rd column. I tried Googling and got zilch. Perhaps my search parameters needed to be more generalized, but I would really appreciate if anyone who understands what I mean can help me figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal workinge example (http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) so that we can see what you have at present and better understand what you're trying to describe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multicol package should solve this problem

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

the *-version diables the balancing

Just for comparison, the version without * gives:
[image]

And the version with star results in:

[image]

Comment: I am using `multicol` and I will use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not forbidden to read the documentation ... Use the star version `multicols*` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting to grips w/LaTeX. I forgot about the documentation...